# Insert URL in database Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I got a website delivered to me, and the dev doesn't reply to me anymore. As a beginner I am trying to find a solution by my own but I can't figure it out.

I would like to add a feature and maybe you guys can help me.

To explain our users can write some comments on a single page, before to be published our moderator is validating the comment, as soon as it is done the user is receiving an email saying your comment Blablabla has been validated.

We would like to add to the email a link to the page where he wrote his comment, as we have a lot of single pages with different URL, it will be easier for him to found his comment back.

So our goal is to save the URL into the database and then I will extract that URL to put it in the email.

I have added in the our user_comment DB the column url_link to store the URL.

Here is my controller, I have added urllink

```
public function add_comment(){
    if ($this->session->userdata('user_id')){
        $comment = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('comment'));
        $pageid = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('page_id'));
        $urllink = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('url_link'));

        $data = array(
            'user_id' => $_SESSION['user_id'],
            'page_id' => $pageid,
            'url_link'  =>$urllink,
            'comment' => $comment,
            'created' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
            'modified' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
        );

        echo $query = $this->page_model->add_comments($data);die;

    }else{
        redirect();
    }
}
```

My model

```
public function add_comments($data){
    if($this->db->insert('user_comment',$data)){
        return 'true';
    }else{
        return 'false';
    }
}
```

My view for the comment section

```
                    <h3>Post a Comment</h3>
                    <?php if ($this->session->userdata('user_id')){?>
                    <div class="textarea_editor" style="clear:left; ">
                         <div class="textarea_editorinner">
                            <div id="editor" data-id="<?php if(!empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){ echo $_SESSION['user_id'];}else{ echo '';}?>"></div>
                            <textarea name="comment"  style="display:none" id="hiddenArea" class="add_comment"></textarea>
                          </div>
               <?php }else{?>
                <div class="write-comment">
                            <input style="margin-left:10px; " type="text"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#user_login" placeholder="Type your comment" class="add_comment">
                   <?php }?>
                        
                        <?php 
                        if ($this->session->userdata('user_id')){?>
                            <button class="sendmessage sendmessageclick" data-d-id="<?php echo $pages[0]->pageId;?>"><span class="far fa-paper-plane">
                            
                            </span><span class="d-none d-block-sm">Send</span></button>
                        <?php }?>
                    
                    </div>
                </div>
```

My common.js

$('.sendmessageclick').click(function(){

```
    $('#hiddenArea').val(quill.container.firstChild.innerHTML);
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        async: false,
        data:{page_id:$(this).attr('data-d-id'),comment:$('.add_comment').val()},
        url: static_url+'/pages/add_comment',
        success: function(result){
            $('.add_comment').val('');
            if(result == 'true'){
                $('.comment_alert').show();
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.comment_alert').hide();
                    location.reload();
                }, 3000);
            }else{
                alert('Error');
                location.reload();
            }
            
            console.clear();
        }
    });
});
```

Everything is working perfectly, except URL, for sure I am missing something to indicate the URL to be stored in the DB.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? As far as I can see, you haven't written any code that stores the URL along the comment

Comment: Yes, I am trying to learn along the process, so for know haven't tried much. I am more looking for some guidance, which direction to go.

Comment: The first step would be: checking what that code does, and what is missing. Then implement the missing pieces

Comment: Send that url_link also through Ajax on the controller to insert it into the database........you have not sended the url only comment and page_id is sended.

Comment: ok, I will add it, I guess I should add url_link:$(this).attr('url-link')
And in my view I am adding url-link="<?php echo $url[0]->url_link;?>"

Answer (score 0):

As I can see your controller collect three POST variables they are 'comment', 'page_id', and 'url_link'. However, if you look at your view code only 'comment' is sent.

A simple solution would be to add two additional input boxes having the name 'page_id', and 'url_link'.

```
<h3>Post a Comment</h3>
    <?php if ($this->session->userdata('user_id')){?>
    <div class="textarea_editor" style="clear:left; ">
         <div class="textarea_editorinner">
            <div id="editor" data-id="<?php if(!empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){ echo $_SESSION['user_id'];}else{ echo '';}?>"></div>
            <textarea name="comment"  style="display:none" id="hiddenArea" class="add_comment"></textarea>
            <input type='hidden' name='page_id' value='<<Page ID value added by PHP>>'>
            <input type='text' name='url_link' value=''>
          </div>
```

```
<div class="write-comment">
            <input style="margin-left:10px; " type="text"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#user_login" placeholder="Type your comment" class="add_comment">
   <?php }?>
        
        <?php 
        if ($this->session->userdata('user_id')){?>
            <button class="sendmessage sendmessageclick" data-d-id="<?php echo $pages[0]->pageId;?>"><span class="far fa-paper-plane">
            
            </span><span class="d-none d-block-sm">Send</span></button>
        <?php }?>
    
    </div>
</div>
```